# Cannot remove ceiling recessed canned light trim/can

Tags: wiring, ceiling, recessed-lighting

I'm trying to replace my kitchen ceiling recessed canned light/trim. I turned the breaker off.

I cannot see or feel any springs on the exterior or interior of the can. I've tried twisting the trim counter-clockwise but that doesn't do anything. I've also tried gently pulling down on the trim and can but cannot get it to budge.

Any ideas how to remove this trim or can?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Please note this is a ceiling light (not a wall light as the last photo would lead you to believe, it’s just rotated incorrectly)

Comment: The last picture implies that it did "budge" but stuck after a short distance...

Comment: If you're replacing them, start removing absolutely everything you can. Especially look for 3 slots at the ceiling junction. (If there's a discrete tab at the top of those slots, pull those down.) There's a good chance they were built in before drywall was applied, so might require a good bit of destruction to remove.

Comment: Certainly remove the visible screws in the second picture, and any others that become visible. You won't know until you know whether they were new construction or "pop a hole in the drywall and stuff" but both can be tedious to remove. The former does tend to need a lot of unscrewing as you basically take the light fixture apart to get it out.The latter often are not well set up to remove, period, or require foreknowledge of what trick that one used.

Comment: There are clips on both sides of the socket. Try squeezing them toward the socket. The trim could come away from the socket.

Comment: There are probably spring loaded clips holding it in place.  My experience is that they tend to trash the ceiling, if you are just pulling.  Just unscrew any screws you see, and hopefully that will dismantle one or both of the clips.

Comment: I'd just grab opposite sides with 2 channel locks and bend the cup in on itself.